First order approximation of function at $x=y$
Given two unit vectors $x, y\in S^n$, is there a way to obtain a 1st order aproximation at $x=y$ of the following function?:
$$ f(x, y) := \arccos(x^\top y) \frac{y-(x^\top y)x}{\lVert y- (x^\top y) x\rVert} $$
An alternative formulation may be the one resulting from defining $z := y - (x^\top y) x$, which leads to
$$ f(z) := \arccos(\sqrt{1-z^\top z}) \frac{z}{\lVert z\rVert} $$
Thus, the linearization point becomes $z=[0, 0, 0]^\top$. However, I have had no sucess in obtaining a Taylor approximation of $f(z)$.
